# How to import MaxMind local data, CSV files into redis in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, redis, geoip, maxmind

I need to import CSV files provided by Maxmind into Redis in a Ruby on Rails application.

In this [link](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) they have provided way for a SQL database but not for NoSQL Databases.

Comment: There are have ruby c binding https://github.com/mtodd/geoip too. Maybe it outdated now, but early it was very fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this gem:

```
https://github.com/zabolotnov87/geoip_redis
```

It was quite easy to implement it.

Other solution I found was:

```
https://redislabs.com/ebook/part-2-core-concepts/chapter-5-using-redis-for-application-support/5-3-ip-to-city-and-country-lookup/5-3-1-loading-the-location-tables/
https://redislabs.com/ebook/part-2-core-concepts/chapter-5-using-redis-for-application-support/5-3-ip-to-city-and-country-lookup/5-3-2-looking-up-cities/
```

They have described it properly for loading csv files and looking up cities but the code is in python.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any ready tutorial to import Maxmind into Redis. However, I have seen a tutorial to import IP2Location into Redis and querying it. You can refer to this article and then update the CSV parameters according to Maxmind.

https://www.ip2location.com/tutorials/importing-ip2location-data-into-redis-and-querying-with-php

I wish I could be more useful but this is best reference I could found.